# XPath to get values using AgilityPack from HTML page

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need to get numeric values from a web page into two variables.

A snippet from the page is below

```
<b>Downloads (current version):</b> 123                  <br />
<b>Downloads (total):</b> 253</td>
<br />
```

The "Downloads (current version):" and "Downloads (total):" are unique strings in the page.

I need to get the "123" and "253" into variables

**Edit:** Thanks to har07 I ended up with

```
var downloadscurrentversion = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//b[.='Downloads (current version):']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
var downloadsallversions = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//b[.='Downloads (total):']/following-sibling::text()[1]");

Console.WriteLine("Total: " + downloadsallversions.InnerText.Trim());
Console.WriteLine("Current: " + downloadscurrentversion.InnerText.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example :

```
var html = @"<div>
<b>Downloads (current version):</b> 123                  <br />
<b>Downloads (total):</b> 253</td>
<br />
</div>";
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div/text()[normalize-space(.)]");
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

this part of XPath from above example :

```
/div/text()
```

means, select all text nodes those are direct child of `<div>` element. And the last part :

```
[normalize-space(.)]
```

filters out empty text nodes.

**UPDATE :**

Responding to your comment, you can try this way instead :

```
var result = 
        htmlDoc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes(@"/div/b[.='Downloads (current version):' 
                                        or 
                                     .='Downloads (total):']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
```

Above XPath selects text node that is directly after specific `<b>` elements.

Comment: Your code finds the 123 and 253 but I only included a small snippet of the complete HTML page.  If I run it on the actual page I get a lot of extra results I don't want.  Somehow the XPath needs to look specifically for the "Downloads (current version):" and "Downloads (total):" text and only return results after finding each of them.

Comment: updated my answer to select text node based on previous `<b>` elements.

Comment: Thanks,  I ended up with    var downloadscurrentversion =          htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//b[.='Downloads (current version):']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
    var downloadsallversions = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//b[.='Downloads (total):']/following-sibling::text()[1]");

    Console.WriteLine("Total: " + downloadsallversions.First().InnerText.Trim());
    Console.WriteLine("Current: " + downloadscurrentversion.First().InnerText.Trim());